# How do I add a keybinding in VS Code when a file exists?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to run `npm run start` when I press F5, but only when the file, `package.json` exists in the root of the project (i.e. when the folder open is a Node.js project).

To illustrate what I'm trying to do, let's pretend that `file.exists package.json` does what I want it to (which it doesn't).

`~/.config/Code/User/keybindings.json`:

```
[
  {
    "key": "f5",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": {
        "text": "npm run start\r"
    },
    "when": "file.exists package.json"
  },
]
```

What is the correct way to do this? I can't see anything related to testing if a file exists in the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the extension (I wrote) [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) v1.55.0 and the command [`extension.commandvariable.inTerminal`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#interminal)

```json
  {
    "key": "f5",
    "command": "extension.commandvariable.inTerminal",
    "args": {
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.transform",
      "args": { "text": "npm run start" },
      "addCR": true,
      "when": "file.exists ${workspaceFolder}${pathSeparator}package.json"
    }
  }
```

The keybinding will **always** execute. The `when` test is performed in the command not before the command execution. If you use `F5` then you lose the default launch functionality.

Comment: Heh, I took a wild guess with `file.exists` and it turns out I was just an extension away from making it work. Thanks very much.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to `else run default keybinding`.

Comment: @NickBolton I implemented your suggestion, it looks logical. AFAIK there is no hook in the keybinding handling, you could add an `else` argument and then specify the default command, I can't "rethrow/inject" the key and magically let it choose a different binding. Maybe extension **multi-command** could add some conditional tests to execute the next command in the list

Answer (score 0):

Based on [rioV8's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76760835/47775), I expanded upon the solution by showing the terminal:

```json
  {
    "key": "f5",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
      "commands": [
        "workbench.action.terminal.focus",
        {
          // depends on: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable
          "command": "extension.commandvariable.inTerminal",
          "args": {
            "command": "extension.commandvariable.transform",
            "args": { "text": "npm run start" },
            "addCR": true,
            "when": "file.exists ${workspaceFolder}${pathSeparator}package.json"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
  },
```